# Notification code not working

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am unsure why my simple javascript code is not working. Not getting any errors in the console either. Any help would be much appreciated.

when i click on the id `#notificationLink` the id `#notificationContainer` does not appear (I initially have it in my css as `display:none` under `#notificationContainer`)

application.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav_content">
 <li class="notification_li">
  <span id="notification_count">1</span>
  <%= link_to '', '#', id: "notificationLink", class: "fa fa-bell" %>
  <div id="notificationContainer">
   <div id="notificationTitle">Notifications</div>
   <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications">I am the general notification</div>
   <div id="notificationFooter"><a href="#">See All</a></div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
    $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
    $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
  });
  //Document Click hiding the popup 
  $(document).click(function() {
    $("#notificationContainer").hide();
  });
  //Popup on click
  $("#notificationContainer").click(function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

navigatin.css.scss

```
/*----- notification: general_notification -----*/
#notification_count {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 4px;
  background: #b14525;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

#notificationLink:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#notificationContainer {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: -190px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none; /*info: Enable this after jquery implementation*/ 
}

#notificationContainer:before { /*info: Popup Arrow*/
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent white;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 188px;
}

#notificationTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 384px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#notificationsBody {
  padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px !important;
  min-height: 300px;
}

#notificationFooter {
  background-color: #e9eaed;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: What jQuery version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Turbolinks gem? It breaks some existing events like $(document).ready() because the page is never reloaded.

Have you tried

```
var loaded = function() {
    $("#notificationLink").click(function() {
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(300);
        $("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });

    //Document Click hiding the popup 
    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#notificationContainer").hide();
    });

    //Popup on click
    $("#notificationContainer").click(function() {
        return false;
    });
};

$(document).ready(loaded);  // Normal non turbolink page load
$(document).on('page:load', loaded);    //  turbolink page load
```

I say that because your javascript works fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8muquac/). I can only assume that you `link_to` the current notification page and document ready is never called.

Comment: I changed to $(document).on('page:load', function() but did not work. i am using a gem called 'turbolinks'

Comment: I edited it above take a look, tell me if copying to code in doesn't work

Comment: Alternatively what if you try surrounding your `link_to` with a div with the id `notifcationLink` and not in the `link_to`. It will help narrow down the problem

Comment: Thank you @deepak. it was mainly to do with turbo links. 1.) i commented out the gem 'gem 'turbo links' in the gem file. 2.)my application.html.erb i changed "<%= javascript_include_tag "application" 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>" to this <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> 3.) in my application.js i removed "//= require turbo links" - many thanks, it now works